# Best way to communicate to Catia via Browser

Tags: dll, google-chrome-extension, com, activex, npapi

I have a question and was hoping that you could maybe help me out. I currently built an API to communicate between Catia (CAD-Application) and my browser so I can create parts/products read and write parameters etc.

One of my problems is that the only way I know to do this is via ActiveX which I really don't wanna do as it forces everyone to use IE11. Since CatiaV5 is a pretty old Software there won't be any elegant way to use it via some sort of Restful api or similar.

Since I've been working with JavaScript for a while now, did apps for phones but have no idea about browser extensions my question was this. Is it possible to write a Chrome Extension that actually uses com dlls and enables me to set up a connection to a piece of software (in this case Catia) and work with it.
NPAPI plug-ins could be the solution for my problem as it looks from the information I found but it's also supposed to also being phased out.

Do you think it's still worth looking into deeper and studying on writing such an NPAPI app or is there maybe a more elegant way you can think of?

Would be happy for some ideas and suggestions. Thanks in advance and

Greetings Chris

Comment: See [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers the only way to do this would be using native messaging:

- [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging)
- [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging)

[FireBreath2](http://www.firebreath.org/display/fb2/FireBreath+2.0+Home) has an abstraction for building c++ plugins which supports native messaging, though the docs are still a little sparse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems kinda like what I was looking for. One thing I don't really understand yet. Do I implement my com .dlls for communicating with the com-server/application directly or does this mean that you basically have to rewrite it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; you can have your native message host use COM to communicate with something, if that's what you're asking

Comment: You got it right. I want that host to more or less meme the ActiveXObject which will be missing in Chrome. 
The perfect solution would be if all the methods that were used on the ActiveXObject could now be added to the object the PlugIn will return. The thing is that controls on my website need to interact with the plugin on the one end and on the other the plugin has to be able to communicate with the com-server

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to mimick the ActiveXObject because generally that would provide synchronous APIs while native messaging is inherently asynchronous.  You could certainly provide a javascript abstraction which would work for both, though

Answer (score 0):

Zetakey browser support NPAPI.
We provide HTML5 browser embedded system for industrial and enterprise application.

Www.zetakey.com

Best regards,
Jack Wong